# How can I make a program get a variable inside a loop? (java)

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

i am making a program that is asking for your age but it isn't working. 
First it asks how old you are, with the scanner module and puts your age inside a variable. I want to output at the end your age, but it needs a int, so if you put a string or something else it gives a error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at org.asking.age.main(asking.java:18)
```

I want to let him say instead of the error): please only enter a number between 1 and 100, if you enter something else then a number between 1-100. And if you put in a wrong number it has to 'restart', and if it is a good number it has to end.

i tried a loop:

(i = the age from the scanner)

```
while(i>100 || i>0)
        {
            if (a < 100 || a > 0) {

                System.out.println("please only enter a number between 1 and 100");
                System.out.println("how old are you?");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                int a = s.nextInt();

        {
System.out.println("you are " + a + "years old") 
    }}}}}
```

but at the beginning the 'if' cant reach the a variable. does there exist another/any way to do this?

Thanks for helping, and sorry for my bad english :)

Thanks @TheLostMind for helping now i got this code :

but i dont understand how to use the if(>0 && <100, and the matches isn't working

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println("how old are you?");

    Scanner h = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a= h.nextLine();

    String str = a;

    String matches=("\\d+");

    Integer.parseInt(a);



    {
do {


   System.out.println("please only enter a number between 1 and 100");
   System.out.println("how old are you?");
   h.nextLine();

} while(a>0 && a<100); }
}
}
```

Comment: define your Scanner outside the while loop

Comment: Decalre both the `Scanner` and `int a` outside the loop.

Comment: your problem is created because you read integer from scanner, and you entered not numeric value. My suggestion will be to use line, then check is it a valid number or something else report error or proceed further, and small side comment, `i>100 || i>0` can be rewritten as `x>0`,

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, start by decalring both `Scanner` and `int a` outside
>   the loop.
>
> Next, use `scanner#nextLine()` to read an entire line of input into a
>   String.
>
> Then use `String#matches("\\d+")` and `Integer.parseInt(inputString)`
>   to parse the int as a number.
>
> Then use `if(>0 && <100)` check.

There are methods in the `Scanner` class (`hasNextInt()`) which wait for an int, but that's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
Declare Scanner and other Variable 

do {
   System.out.println("please only enter a number between 1 and 100");
   System.out.println("how old are you?");

   read variable value from Scanner
} while(check your condition on variable);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The questions in System.out.print and  the scanner should be outside the loop.
Check the while loop, it says >100 instead of <100.